# Pytest, Flask, Celery - Celery NoneType Error

Tags: python, flask, celery, pytest

I have a Flask application using Celery, and the async processing works fine when the app is running locally. However, when I try to test (pytest) a route that uses Celery tasks, I get this error:

```
app/bp_dir/routes.py:12: in <module>
    from app import db, celery_tasks
app/celery_tasks.py:13: in <module>
    @celery.task()
E   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'task'
```

It seems that Celery is not being spun up correctly when I'm testing. I think the underlying question is how to set up pytest fixtures so that routes importing Celery tasks can be tested.

app/celery_tasks.py looks like this:

```
from app import celeryapp

celery = celeryapp.celery

@celery.task()
def example_task():
    time.sleep(3)
    return 1
```

app/**init**.py

```
...
from app import celeryapp


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    ...

    # Celery
    celery = celeryapp.create_celery_app(app)
    celeryapp.celery = celery

    ...


    return app
```

app/celeryapp/**init**.py

```
from celery import Celery

CELERY_TASK_LIST = [
    'app.celery_tasks',
]

db_session = None
celery = None

def create_celery_app(_app=None):
    """
    Create a new Celery object and tie together the Celery config to the app's config.
    Wrap all tasks in the context of the Flask application.
    :param _app: Flask app
    :return: Celery app
    """

    from app import db

    celery = Celery(_app.import_name,
                    backend=_app.config['CELERY_BACKEND_URL'],
                    broker=_app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
                    include=CELERY_TASK_LIST)

    celery.conf.update(_app.config)
    always_eager = _app.config['TESTING'] or False
    celery.conf.update({'TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER': always_eager,
                        'CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND': 'redis'})

    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not celery.conf.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER:
                with _app.app_context():
                    return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                # special pytest setup
                db.session = db_session
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        def after_return(self, status, retval, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
            """
            After each Celery task, teardown our db session.
            FMI: https://gist.github.com/twolfson/a1b329e9353f9b575131
            Flask-SQLAlchemy uses create_scoped_session at startup which avoids any setup on a
            per-request basis. This means Celery can piggyback off of this initialization.
            """
            if _app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN']:
                if not isinstance(retval, Exception):
                    db.session.commit()

            # If we aren't in an eager request (i.e. Flask will perform teardown), then teardown
            if not celery.conf.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER:
                db.session.remove()

    celery.Task = ContextTask


    return celery
```

app/celeryapp/celery_worker.py

```
from app import celeryapp, create_app

app = create_app()
celery = celeryapp.create_celery_app(app)
celeryapp.celery = celery
```

The code for the Celery set up is mostly borrowed from this [repo]https://github.com/kwiersma/flask-celery-sqlalchemy. The repo has tests [here]https://github.com/kwiersma/flask-celery-sqlalchemy/tree/master/tests, but I can't really see what I'm missing.

/testing_fixtures.py

```
import re
import flask
import pytest
from app import create_app, db

EMAIL = 'testemail@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'Password123!'

def get_codes(data_structure):
    return [(str(x)) for x in range(len(data_structure))]

def extract_csrf_token(response: flask.Response) -> str:
    # is there better way to get CSRF token? I couldn't find one
    return re.search('name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="([^"]*)"', str(response.data)).group(1)

@pytest.fixture
def flask_app():
    app = create_app()
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite://"
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'this is crucial for storing section'
    app.testing = True

    return app

@pytest.fixture
def app_context(flask_app):
    with flask_app.app_context():
        yield

@pytest.fixture
def setup_db(app_context):
    db.create_all()

@pytest.fixture
def test_client(setup_db, flask_app):
    with flask_app.test_client() as c:
        yield c

@pytest.fixture
def registered_user(test_client, flask_app):
    resp = test_client.get("/auth/register")  # to get csrf_token
    csrf_token = extract_csrf_token(resp)

    # follow_redirect=False is important - otherwise you won't be able to tell the difference between successful
    # and faulty registration
    resp = test_client.post('/auth/register',
                            data={'email': EMAIL, 'password': PASSWORD, 'password2': PASSWORD,
                                  'csrf_token': csrf_token, 'is_test':True},
                            follow_redirects=False)
    assert resp.status_code == 302, "/auth/register should redirect on successful registering"

@pytest.fixture
def logged_client(registered_user, test_client):
    resp = test_client.get("/auth/login")  # to get csrf_token
    csrf_token = extract_csrf_token(resp)

    resp = test_client.post('/auth/login', data={'email': EMAIL, 'password': PASSWORD, 'csrf_token': csrf_token})

    assert resp.status_code == 302, "/auth/login should redirect to another page on successful login"

    yield test_client

    resp = test_client.get('/auth/logout')
    assert resp.status_code == 302
```

Example test:

```
from testing_fixtures import *

def test_example_route(logged_client):
    response = logged_client.get('/example_route')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Example route:

```
from app import db, celery_tasks
...

@example_bp.route('/example_route')
def example_route():

    return 1
```

Comment: Have you tried suggestions [enabling pytest for celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/testing.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a tricky knot to untie, so I'll offer a slight restructuring.

First, note that you don't need an instance of Celery to declare tasks.

```
import celery

@celery.task
def mytask():
    ...
```

is sufficient.

Now, consider creating an instance of Celery in `app/__init__.py`, and defer initializing it until `create_app()` is invoke. Something like

```
celery = Celery(__name__)

def create_app(config_class=...):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    ...
    celery.config_from_object(config_class)
```

might let you do away with `celeryapp` entirely, avoiding most opportunities for import order fouling you up.

I have a working example you can crib from [here](https://github.com/davewsmith/flask-celery-starter/blob/master/app/__init__.py),
or look at what the Flask Mega Tutorial does when it
[introduces Rq](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs), which an alternative to Celery.

Comment: This worked, thank you. One thing I found I needed: in task.py I had to add `from celery import Celery`, `celery_app = Celery()`. Otherwise I would get an error along the lines of, "Object celery has no attribute task". Also for those reading in the future, the code in demo.py is important (I missed it originally). Celery worker runs with `celery -A demo.celery worker --loglevel=debug`